# How can I printscreen in X11 Environment?

Tags: screen-capture, x11, wireshark

I use [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) and it runs under [X11 environment](http://developer.apple.com/opensource/tools/x11.html) I want take some screenshot from wireshark windows but 
<kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>3</kbd>  or <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>4</kbd> or ... didn't work there is there any way that I could take some screen shot in X11 environment?

Comment: What do you see when you cmd shift 4 and selected the region?

Comment: @hobs when I press cmd+shift+4 it types $ in wireshark search box.

Comment: Is Aqua window manager still running or are you in a non-default X11 mode different than simply firing up the standard X11.app after a normal user log in to OS X?

Comment: @bmike I don't know what you mean by Aqua windows manager, if you mean the X111 grey windows, yes it runs and wireshark run within it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to @[calum-benson](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/2841/calum-benson)'s hint, I found what my problem was. I must un-check 1Full-screen mode1 in X11 Preferences.

Answer (score 1):

Click to the desktop or any other application, and then press <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>3</kbd>.

With this method Wireshark will loose the focus and you can grab the whole screen.

Comment: there is no desktop when you cmd+tab to wireshark you go to another envirinment (X11) and if you want click desktop must switch to another application then your solution is useless for my case.

Comment: Not true, resize your wireshark window to have a little smaller and then you can click on the desktop, or use Expose to show the desktop click on it and use Expose to show your application again. I did it and it worked.

Comment: I don't know how you can do it because when I want run wireshark first it rum X11 (a grey environment) then run wireshark into X11 so when I minimize or resize wireshark I just see X11 Grey environment and can't resize it (or minimize)

Comment: On the download page you can download Wireshark images for OSX which starts X11 automatically and runs almost like a normal application.

Comment: If you're seeing "a grey environment" whenever X11 starts up, then X11.app is running in full screen mode. Press Cmd-Opt-A to toggle that, then you should see Wireshark running as a regular window on your desktop, and the other screen grabbing suggestions here should work fine.

Comment: Tanx @Calum this is work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using Grab.app? It supports a "timed screen" capture mode. You'd switch to Grab.app, select "Timed Screen..." then switch back to X11. After 10 seconds it will do a screenshot.